# DB2/iSeries SQL clean up CR/LF, tabs etc

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, replace

I need to find and clean up line breaks, carriage returns, tabs and "SUB"-characters in a set of 400k+ string records, but this DB2 environment is taking a toll on me.

Thought I could do some search and replacing with the REPLACE() and CHR() functions, but it seems CHR() is not available on this system (Error: CHR in *LIBL type *N not found). Working with \t, \r, \n etc doesn't seem to be working either. The chars can be in the middle of strings or at the end of them.

```
DBMS = DB2
System = iSeries
Language = SQL
Encoding = Not sure, possibly EBCDIC
```

Any hints on what I can do with this?

Comment: You could always export the data, process and put it back.  I've done this before. I've used Squirrel SQL to move DB2 tables to MySQL for test before moving back to DB2 into production (Many Gigabytes). Issues with using squirrel include: lack of progress indication, and needing to hold the whole table in memory including SLQ markup so you'll need to increase you Java memory limits. Depends on string size but a few Gigs hopefully would suffice. Also this must be done locally or bandwidth will probably be an issue.

Comment: Oh and one more thing... because of difference in keywords and quoting you might need to apply a couple regular expressions before it can be imported. Really nothing search and replace in a decent text editor shouldn't be able to handle (assuming it can handle at least 400k records!) Oh Squirrel will even write the table definition for you, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to clear up specific characters like carriage return (EBCDIC x'0d')  and line feed (EBCDIC x'25') you should find the [translated character in EBCDIC](http://www.flounder.com/ebcdictoascii1.htm) then use the TRANSLATE() function to replace them with space.

If you just want to remove undisplayable characters then look for anything under x'40'.

Comment: Actually, the line feed is EBCDIC x'25'.  x'0A' is LF in ASCII.

Comment: Good on the explanation of how it works, and some kudos to @FroggyTX to providing a practical example.

Answer (score 10):

I used this SQL to find x'25' and x'0D':

```
SELECT 
     <field>
    , LOCATE(x'0D', <field>) AS "0D" 
    , LOCATE(x'25', <field>) AS "25" 
    , length(trim(<field>)) AS "Length"
FROM <file> 
WHERE   LOCATE(x'25', <field>) > 0 
    OR  LOCATE(x'0D', <field>) > 0
```

And I used this SQL to replace them:

```
UPDATE <file> 
SET <field> = REPLACE(REPLACE(<field>, x'0D', ' '), x'25', ' ')
WHERE   LOCATE(x'25', <field>) > 0 
    OR  LOCATE(x'0D', <field>) > 0
```

Comment: Nice Solution for anyone using v5r3 or higher, which is required for the replace function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an sample script that replaces `X'41'` by `X'40'`. Something that was creating issues at our shop:

```
UPDATE [yourfile] SET [yourfield] = TRANSLATE([yourfield], X'40', 
X'41') WHERE [yourfield] like '%' concat X'41' concat '%'
```

If you need to replace more than one character, extend the "to" and "from" hexadecimal strings to the values you need in the `TRANSLATE` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try TRANSLATE or REPLACE.

The brute force method involves using POSITION to find the errant character, then SUBSTR before and after it.  CONCAT the two substrings (less the undesirable character) to re-form the column.

The character encoding is almost certainly one of the EBCDIC character sets.  Depending on how the table got loaded in the first place, the CR may be x'0d' and the LF x'15', x'25'.  An easy way to find out is to get to a green screen and do a DSPPFM against the table.  Press F10 then F11 to view the table is raw, hexadecimal (over/under) format.

Answer (score 1):

For details on the available functions see the 
[DB2 for i5/OS SQL Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzmst02.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `TRANSLATE()` function will serve your needs.

```
    TRANSLATE( data, tochars, fromchars )
```

...where *fromchars* is the set of characters you don't want, and *tochars* is the corresponding characters you want them replaced with.  You may have to write this out in hex format, as `x'nnnnnn...'` and you will need to know what character set you are working with.
Using the `DSPFFD` command on your table should show the CCSID of your fields.

Answer (score 1):

we struggled a lot to replace the new line char and carriage return from flat file.

Finally we used below sql to sort the issue.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, CHR(13), ''), CHR(10), '')
```

Try it out

```
CR = CHR(13)
LF = CHR(10)
```