# DB2 to COBOL String Losing Line Feed and Carriage Returns

Tags: sql, db2, cobol

i'm trying to grab some data out of a table. The Variable is VARCHAR 30000 and when I use COBOL EXEC SQL to retrieve it, the string is returned but without the necessary (hex) Line Feeds and Carriage Returns. I inspect the string one character at a time looking for the Hex Values of 0A or 0D but they never come up.

The LF and CR seem to be lost as soon as fill the string into my cobol variable.

Ideas?

Comment: You don't specify the source of the data, are you certain the column contains the x'0A' and x'0D' ?  If you try retrieving the data with some other tool, are those values present?

Comment: You know that unless you include those particular hex-values which relate to CR and LF, as data, they won't be stored in a z/OS DB2 VARCHAR. Yes? You're not just assuming that z/OS and COBOL have "strings", because they don't.

Comment: Why not look for the ebcdic New-Line charachter (x'15' dec=21 ??). Most java programs are happy working with ebcdic and will treat the ebcdic new line correctly

Comment: If stored as EBCDIC, a CR/LF combination should be x'0D25'. Hard to know how to answer without knowing how it's stored, how it's retrieved, how the `inspect` is done, etc. We need to see related code.

Comment: The problem was that the particular record I was looking at had in fact no CRLF in the data, but the one that I was comparing it to did. The CRLF were in fact stored in the DB2 VARCHAR ( as hex values). Thank you for the help. What a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen situations where CR and LF were in data in the database.  These are valid characters so it's possible for them to be stored there.

Have you tried to confirm that there really are CR and LF characters in the database using some other tool or method?  My Z-Series experience is quite limited, so I'm unable to suggest options.  However, there must be some equivalent of SSMS and SQL Server on the Z-Series to query the DB2 database.

Check out this SO link on querying DB2 and cleaning up CR and LF characters.

[DB2/iSeries SQL clean up CR/LF, tabs etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573321/db2-iseries-sql-clean-up-cr-lf-tabs-etc)

Comment: It is something of a Programmer 101 tenet when one says "It's not here" for someone else to ask, "How can you be sure?"

Answer (score 1):

If the data is stored / **converted** to ebcdic when **retrieved** on the mainframe, you should get the EBCDIC New-Line characters x'15' decimal=21 rather than 0A or 0D.

It is only if you are retrieving the data in ASCII / UTF-8 that you would get 0A or 0D.

---

Most java editors can edit EBCDIC (with the EBCDIC New-Line Character x'15') just as easily as ASCII (with \n), not sure about Eclipse though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe this could be dialect dependent (both COBOL and DB2) but if it were me I would be using FOR BIT DATA on the VARCHAR in the table definition.  Your issue could also relate to the code page defined for the database in which the table resides.

I routinely store all kinds of binary, EBCDIC and Unicode data mixed within the same VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA column with no problems, and all you are trying to do is include CR & LF.  My approach works in both DB2 z/OS and DB2 LUW.

I hope this helps.